# How to show most recent photos in UIImagePicker?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

Is it possible to sort the images/videos shown in the Image Picker, so that only the photos from the current day will appear?

This is what I have so far

```
pickerMain = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
pickerMain.delegate  = self;
[pickerMain setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];
[self presentViewController:pickerMain animated:YES completion:^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO
                                            withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];


}];
pickerMain.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, kUTTypeImage, nil];
[pickerMain setVideoMaximumDuration:15.0f];
```

Comment: You need to show photos only from library? is that what you mean with most recent photos?

Comment: I would like to show any photos in the saved photos album that are from today. @ReinierMelian

Comment: Sorry I miss that part of your question, I am working on it

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to sort the images/videos shown in the Image Picker, so that only the photos from the current day will appear?

Not using UIImagePickerController, no. You would have to write your own picker.